# Any ways to speed up this C++ AMP code?

Tags: c++

Today I learned the basics of c++ amp for the purpose of maybe using it for a plugin I'm writing. The plugin needs to do a lot of edge vs triangle intersection tests so I wrote this test code to see if its a viable option.

The function for processing and data quantities are real, the data itself just random stuff.

To my disappointment, the AMP version runs ~3 times slower than even the unoptimized cpu version (i tried to keep the functions as similar as possible). The problem seems to be the part where I write to the result view (all though, i suspect that by commenting that bit out the entire shader gets snipped by the compiler).

Anyway, I have an optimized cpu version that runs ~20 times faster than the cpu version in the test code and its still way too slow. Is there any hope for the AMP version to catch up and surpass that?

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_math.h>
#include <random>
using namespace concurrency;

struct point3 {
    float a, b, c;
    point3() {
        a = rand() % 100;
        b = rand() % 100;
        c = rand() % 100;
    }
};

struct thing {
    point3 center;
    float radius;
};

int lastTick;
timeb tb;
int tick() {
    int hold = lastTick;
    ftime(&tb);
    lastTick = tb.millitm + (tb.time & 0xfffff) * 1000;
    return lastTick - hold;
}

int main()
{
    system("PAUSE");

    std::vector<thing> faces(13500);
    std::vector<thing> edges(20000);
    std::vector<int> results(faces.size() * edges.size());
    array_view<const thing> v1(faces.size(), faces);
    array_view<const thing> v2(edges.size(), edges);
    array_view<int> vr(results.size(), results);

    int nFaces = faces.size();
    int nEdges = edges.size();

    tick();
    for (int x = 0; x < nFaces; x++) {
        thing* face = &faces[x];

        int a, b, c;
        thing* edge;

        for (int y = 0; y < nEdges; y++) {
            edge = &edges[y];
            a = edge->center.a - face->center.a;
            b = edge->center.b - face->center.b;
            c = edge->center.c - face->center.c;
            results[x * nFaces + y] = (sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c) < (face->radius + edge->radius)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "cpu time: " << tick() << "\n";

    v1.refresh();
    v2.refresh();

    parallel_for_each(v1.extent, [=](index<1> x) restrict(amp) {
        const thing* face = &v1[x];

        int a, b, c;
        const thing* edge;

        for (int y = 0; y < nEdges; y++) {
            edge = &v2[y];
            a = edge->center.a - face->center.a;
            b = edge->center.b - face->center.b;
            c = edge->center.c - face->center.c;
            vr[x * nFaces + y] = (fast_math::sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c) < (face->radius + edge->radius)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });

    vr.synchronize();
    std::cout << "gpu time: " << tick() << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: This question is more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You could simplify your code by creating subtraction methods for your `Thing` class.  Also, adding a distance method would help too.

Comment: You may get some speed by extracting the `face` ordinates into separate variables before the `parallel_for_each` statement, since they don't change within the loop.

Comment: yea, I was able to get the amp execution time down by some 30% by trying different variations of accessing the data but I've seemingly hit a wall. Even if there are no calculations at all and just data reads and writing a constant to the output, I can't get it any lower than 1 second which might be the overhead of moving things to the gpu and back and whatever parallel_for_each does for getting the ball rolling. All though there is hope yet since doing the gpu test again while the program is still running cuts that time by 50%.

Comment: I think i found the source of slowness.Its the size of the result view, it weighs in at just over 1GB which is the size of my gpu memory so obviously it can't fit there. After chopping it down to 32mb and adding extra logic to bitshift 32 results into one int its now performing 30x faster than the cpu version. I doubt that the results are correct right now due to sync issues but I'll tackle that tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I ditched all the back & forth between the gpu and cpu, I'm doing all the calculations on the gpu side and only bring back the modified vertex buffer after I'm done. Down to 22ms per frame now which is some ~70 times faster than the simd+multithreading cpu solution I had. (thats a 3930k vs gtx560Ti)

Comment: Down to 8ms after manually unrolling some loops and optimizing kernel size, hölymöley! way past my target speed now but this is exciting.